# Starting OWIN Server for tests

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, owin, mstest

I have been trying to set up some tests for a web api 2 project that I am working on. I have tried both of the methods in the following article with some success.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/26/unit-testing-owin-applications-using-testserver.aspx

I hit problems because there are configuration settings in the web.config file that seem to be completely ignored using either of these methods. For instance, the database connection strings and other application settings are ignored.

When I run OwinHost.exe from the root directory of my Web Api project everything works more or less as expected, honouring the settings in web.config.

How do I get the WebApp.Start or TestServer.Create methods to reference the web.config file in the Web API project?

Is there another way to do this that I am missing?